# Applying the Product Rule, but getting two diffent answers

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

> Three officers—a president, a treasurer, and a secretary—are to be chosen
>   from among four people: Ann, Bob, Cyd, and Dan. Suppose that, for various
>   reasons, Ann cannot be president and either Cyd or Dan must be secretary.
>   How many ways can the officers be chosen?

There are three choices for president (all except Ann), three choices for treasurer (all except the one chosen as president), and two choices for secretary(Cyd or Dan). Therefore, by the multiplication rule, there are $3 \cdot 3 \cdot 2 = 18$ choices in all.

But if we choose  the secretary first, then the president, then the treasurer, the answer is $8$.

Why do we get two different answers here?

Comment: In the first case, what happens if Cyd or Dan are chosen as president? In the second case, have you conisedered the possibility of bein Cyd secretary and Dan president?

Comment: If Cyd is chosen as president, then there are $6$ possibilities,I think. But I am not sure that's allowed by the assumptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> There are $3$ choices for president (all except Ann), $3$ choices for treasurer (all except the one chosen as president), and $2$ choices for secretary (Cyd or Dan). Therefore, by the multiplication rule, there are $3 \cdot 3 \cdot 2=183 \cdot 3  \cdot 2=18$ choices in all.

This reasoning is not correct, because there aren't necessarily $2$ choices for secretary. There could be no choices (if Cyd and Dan were chosen as president and treasurer), or $1$ choice (if one of them was chosen as president or treasurer), or $2$ choices (if neither of them was chosen as president or treasurer).

You have to be careful when applying the *multiplication (product) rule*. The rule says that the number of choices for $A$ and $B$ is equal to the number of choices for $A$ times the number of choices for $B$ given the choice for $A$ -- **BUT** it only applies if the number of choices for $B$ does not depend on which choice for $A$ was made.

The correct answer is $8$. Like you suggested, we can get this by choosing secretary first, then president, then treasurer. There will be $2$ choices for each, and fortunately this number will not depend on previous choices, so the multiplication rule applies.

Comment: How do we know the successive choices depend/don't depend on the previous choices? I am new to this and I am not sure what dependent means in this context. Can you elaborate on that a little, please.

Comment: @user371925 You have to think carefully about it. When you got $18$, you said that there were $2$ choices for secretary. But you have already chosen president or treasurer. So maybe the president or treasurer was Cyd or Dan! And then there wouldn't be 2 choices left. Do you see that?

Comment: In the correct answer, we choose the secretary first -- no one has yet been assigned to anything, so Cyd and Dan are definitely both available. Then we choose the president -- it can be anyone except whichever of Cyd and Dan was the secretary, and except Ann, so there are exactly 2 people left. Finally there are 2 people left for treasurer and no constraint on who the treasurer can be, so 2 choices for treasurer.

Answer (score 1):

**Answer corrected following the helpful commentary by 6005**

Considering all possibilities there are eight cases:

$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|} 
\hline \text{T} & \text{S} & \text{P} \\ \hline
\text{A} & \text{C} & \text{B} \\ \hline
\text{A} & \text{C} & \text{D} \\ \hline
\text{A} & \text{D} & \text{B} \\ \hline
\text{A} & \text{D} & \text{C} \\ \hline
\text{B} & \text{C} & \text{D} \\ \hline
\text{B} & \text{D} & \text{C} \\ \hline
\text{C} & \text{D} & \text{B} \\ \hline
\text{D} & \text{C} & \text{B} \\ \hline
\end{array}$$

(T stands for treasurer, S for secretary, P for president, A for Ann, B for Bob, C for Cyd and D for Dan.)

Comment: @6005 Thank you very much for noticing it.

Comment: +1 because sometimes the best way to check if an answer is correct is to write out all the cases, and see.